# Show progress bar while reconnecting to internet

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

When there is no internet, an alert dialog appear with **cancel** and **retry** button, and on **retry** button I am recursively calling **newsResponse() method**.

Now what I want is, on **retry** it should show **progress dialog (means 5 seconds delay)** and when there is no internet then again show alert dialog.

My Code.

```
public void newsResponse() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String str_response = response.toString();
            News news = gson.fromJson(str_response, News.class);
            news_list = news.getArticles();
            newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(NewsActivity.this, news_list);
            newsGridAdapter = new NewsGridAdapter(NewsActivity.this, news_list);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
            gridRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsGridAdapter);
            if (isList) {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                gridRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (!checkInternet()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder connectionBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsActivity.this);
                connectionBuilder.setMessage("Unable to load data!");
                connectionBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                connectionBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                        "Retry",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                newsResponse();
                            }
                        });

                connectionBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                        "Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = connectionBuilder.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
           (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add delay to your progess bar:

```
    public void newsResponse() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String str_response = response.toString();
            News news = gson.fromJson(str_response, News.class);
            news_list = news.getArticles();
            newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(NewsActivity.this, news_list);
            newsGridAdapter = new NewsGridAdapter(NewsActivity.this, news_list);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
            gridRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsGridAdapter);
            if (isList) {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                gridRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (!checkInternet()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder connectionBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsActivity.this);
                connectionBuilder.setMessage("Unable to load data!");
                connectionBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                connectionBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                        "Retry",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
                                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                                pDialog.show();
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        newsResponse();
                                    }
                                }, 5000);
                            }
                        });

                connectionBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                        "Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = connectionBuilder.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
           (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

It will show progress dialog for 5 seconds when you press retry button.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: read my question again, I said when there is no internet my alert dialog appears and when I press retry, it should show connecting and if after 5 seconds internet is not active then again show my alert dialog.

Comment: your header: Show progress bar while reconnecting to internet, your question: Now what I want is, on retry it should show progress bar (means 5 seconds delay). I answered the same adding delay for 5secs then you said not to show pregress bar while getting the data? Can you clarify or edit the question? Thank you! PS: seems like you deleted your comment

Comment: Nice thing you figured it out!

Comment: thanks, I moved your code in retry button and it worked, you thought I want it while loading, but I want that in retry button.. anyhow it worked :).

Comment: I see! I was lost for some time.